# How to frequency of onTime callback in JWPlayer

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm trying to execute a piece of code that depends on onTime callback from JW player. However, it seems to fire only about 5 times a second or even less! (http://take.ms/2WRJa), which is not sufficient for my needs. How can this frequency be increased?

Relevant example http://output.jsbin.com/xemeru

Comment: It is set, it can't be adjusted.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer the documentation says it could be up to 10 times a second, what determines how many times this is triggered?

Comment: Keyframes in your video might change this. How it is encoded. It isn't a configurable setting though.

Comment: could you elaborate on that please, or maybe point to a site about this? my videos have a frame rate of 29 frames/second, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: How are you encoding the files? What program? Depending on that, you need to add keyframes when encoding the videos.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer, I'm using AWS Elastic Transcoding. Should I contact you through customer support since it seems to be getting too specific?

Comment: I am not on the supper team directly any longer (I just monitor StackOverflow), but there are a few support agents there. I would recommend following up with them.

Comment: You might want to also ask Amazon if they have a way to increase the number of keyframes.